# Vertically center link image in div

Tags: html, css

Hi i'm creating a div which contain a left span and a right image. Both should be centered. I'm using line-height on the text, but this does not seem to work on the img. How can i center it?

```css
.stat-row1 {
    border: 1px solid;
    height: 40px;
}

.stat-row1 span {
   line-height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="stat-row1"><span>1.70</span><span style="float: right; "><a href="https://danskespil.dk/oddset/"><img border="0" style="float: right; height: 30px;" alt="Oddset" src="http://www.ggwp.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/oddset.png"></a></span></div>
```

Comment: Are you referring to vertical or horizontal centering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are already floating the `<span>` to the right, you don't need to float the image itself. Since you have set `line-height`, you can use `vertical-align:middle` on the image.

```css
.stat-row1 {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 40px;
}
.stat-row1 span {
  line-height: 40px;
}
.stat-row1 span.image {
  float: right
}
.stat-row1 span.image img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="stat-row1">
  <span>1.70</span>
  <span class="image">
    <a href="https://danskespil.dk/oddset/">
      <img border="0" alt="Oddset" src="http://www.ggwp.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/oddset.png">
    </a>
   </span>
</div>
```